# Nested grouping in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

### Problem

Consider the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO 
data = StringIO(""",ID,category,app,duplicated
    0,100,OperatingSystem,Finder,FALSE
    1,100,Browser,Chrome,FALSE
    2,100,Browser,Chrome,TRUE
    3,100,Browser,Chrome,FALSE
    4,100,Clipboard,Clipboard,FALSE
    5,200,Browser,Chrome,FALSE
    6,200,Browser,Chrome,TRUE
    7,200,Browser,Chrome,FALSE
    8,200,Clipboard,Clipboard,FALSE
    9,300,OperatingSystem,Finder,FALSE
    10,300,Browser,Chrome,TRUE
    11,300,OperatingSystem,Finder,FALSE
    12,300,Clipboard,Clipboard,FALSE
""" )
df_stack = pd.read_csv(data, index_col=0).fillna('')
```

Using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64122482/1440037)

```py
s = df_stack.groupby('ID')['duplicated'].apply(lambda d : d.ne(d.shift()).cumsum())
d_groups = df_stack.groupby(s)
for g, dataframes in d_groups:
    print(f"\n[Group {g}] - {dataframes['duplicated'].unique()[0]} \n{'-'*20}")
    for index,row in dataframes.iterrows():
        print(index, row['duplicated'], row['category'], row['app'])
```

I get 3 different groups, depicted in the image below, following these conditions:

- Group A: for each ID, all False rows until the first True row of that ID
- Group B: all true rows
- Group C: for each ID, all False rows after the last True row of that ID

### What I want

I want to **group A,B,C by category** in order to obtain 6 groups in total (right side of image).

[image]

EDIT: I solved this with a double for loop, looping over `d_groups` and grouping the inner groups. Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: i think you can try `df_stack.groupby([s, 'category'])`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma it works! if you write it as an answer I'll mark it as solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need need to `groupby` the dataframe `df_stack` on `s` along with `category` to get the desired result, so instead of grouping only by `s`:

```
d_groups = df_stack.groupby(s)
```

**You should `groupby` on `s` along with `category` column:**

```
d_groups = df_stack.groupby([s, 'category'])
```

**Result:**

```
[Group (1, 'Browser')] - False 
--------------------
1 100 False Browser Chrome
5 200 False Browser Chrome

[Group (1, 'OperatingSystem')] - False 
--------------------
0 100 False OperatingSystem Finder
9 300 False OperatingSystem Finder

[Group (2, 'Browser')] - True 
--------------------
2 100 True Browser Chrome
6 200 True Browser Chrome
10 300 True Browser Chrome

[Group (3, 'Browser')] - False 
--------------------
3 100 False Browser Chrome
7 200 False Browser Chrome

[Group (3, 'Clipboard')] - False 
--------------------
4 100 False Clipboard Clipboard
8 200 False Clipboard Clipboard
12 300 False Clipboard Clipboard

[Group (3, 'OperatingSystem')] - False 
--------------------
11 300 False OperatingSystem Finder
```